# C# nicer way of writing if statement with two values

Tags: c#

I was wondering if anyone could please tell me a nicer way of writing this. These are the only conditions that are used.

```
        private static void BondedNonBoundedIndicator(InvoiceLine invoiceLine, Product packageProduct)
        {
            var value = packageProduct.BondedQuantity;
            var value2 = packageProduct.NonBondedQuantity;

            if (value == 0 && value2 == 1)
            {
                invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator = "N";
            }

            if (value == 1 && value2 == 0)
            {
                invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator = "Y";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using `else`, if it fits your logic? Which result is expected, when both values are `0` or `1`?

Comment: Nicer in what way? More concise?  Also, are `0` and `1` the only possible values for `value` and `value2`?  Is it possible for both variables to be `0`, or for both to be `1`, and what is supposed to happen to `invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator` in that case?

Comment: the values can have a combination but these are the only two conditions that effect the result otherwise the result will be blank.

Comment: The only things I would change here is the names of `value` and `value2` and some better named constants for `"N"` and `"Y"`. Maybe adding `else` to make it clear that both can't be true at the same time. The rest is properly structured and easy to read and the length is fine.

Comment: @gkkkab What do you mean by "blank"? Do you mean the empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using C# 8, we can use tuples and the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) to simplify this:

```
invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator = (value, value2) switch {
    (0, 1) => "N",
    (1, 0) => "Y",
    _ => invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator
};
```

You could shorten the last case even further if you know the `invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator` before the code is run is always, say `""`(, then the last case would be `_ => ""`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use xor logic
If(value1^value2  == 1)
    value1 == 0 ? invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator = "N" : invoiceLine.BondedORBbondedIndicator = "Y";

Comment: Without knowing what the other possible values are for `value` and `value2`, there's no way to know whether the bitwise XOR operator `^` would have the intended effect.

Comment: You are right, This relevant assuming the values have binary values.